# Appropriate use of notation for showing that prove that every set is isomorphic to a coproduct of $1$-element sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The following question which has three parts is taken from the book:  "Arrows, Structures, and Functors: The Categorical Imperative" by Michael A. Arbib, ‎Fletcher Jones

> Prove that every set is isomorphic to a coproduct of $1$-element sets.

I am having trouble deciding what the appropriate notation I should use. 
The question in mathematical notation asks $A\cong +_{a_i\in A}\{(a_i,i)|i\in I\}$. (Would $A\cong +_{a\in A}\{a\}$ or $A\cong +_{a_i\in A}\{(a_i,1)\}$ be a better notation?)
Basically, I create a bijective function $f(a)=(a, i).$ (would  either $f(a)=(a,1)$ or $f(a)=a$ make for better notation?)  Since isomorphism for sets involve bijective function, and the family of disjoint union of singleton sets is isomorphic to their coproduct, and hence it satisfies the universal mapping property of the coproduct, etc etc.

As already stated, I am not sure what is an appropriate notation for the disjoint union of family of singleton sets, all of them are subsets of a single set.  To illustrate my difficulties with some concrete examples:

If we are given two sets $A_1=\{m,n\}$ and $A_2=\{r,q\}$, then $A_1\cup A_2=\{m,n,r,q\}$, and $A_1\coprod A_2=\{(m,1), (n,1), (r,2), (q,2)\}$.

But if we only have one set $B=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$, then we can have the list of singleton subsets as $(\{a_i\}|i=1,2,3)$, so $B=\cup_{(a_i\in B|
i=1,2,3)}\{a_i\}$ and $\coprod \{(a_i,i)\}=\{(a_i,i)|a_i\in B,i=1.2.3\}$.  But if I want to emphasis that there is only one set $C$ and denoting that as $C=C_1$ and the elements of $C=C_1=\{b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n,\cdots\}$, then taking the union and disjoint union of singletons of $C$ can be written respectively as $C=\cup_{(b_i\in C|
i\in I)}\{b_i\}$ and $\coprod \{(b_i,i)\}=\{(b_i,i)|b_i\in C,i\in I\}$.  However if I want to emphasis that there is only one set $C_1$, then $C_1=\cup_{(b_i\in C_1|
i\in I)}\{b_i\}$ and $\coprod \{(b_i,1)\}=\{(b_i,1)|b_i\in C_1,i\in I\}$.  But for purposes of clarity, which should I settle on:  $\coprod \{(b_i,i)\}=\{(b_i,i)|b_i\in C,i\in I\}$ or $\coprod \{(b_i,1)\}=\{(b_i,1)|b_i\in C_1,i\in I\}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You often use the notation $i$ and $I$ when it's not at all clear what those refer to. You're borrowing that notation from a place where it makes sense and using it in places where it doesn't make sense. If $A$ is a set, then the set of singletons from $A$ is $\{\,\{a\}\mid a\in A\,\}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @blargoner it seems I can either use $\{(a_i,i)| a_i\in A, i\in I\}$ or $\{(a_i,1)| a_i\in A_1, i\in I\}$ when it is not know if $I$ is a finite or an infinite set.   Not sure which option would cause the least ambiguity.  I mean from what you have seen, what is the common convention for such case.