# Good set builder notation for denoting associativity of coproduct

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, index-notation, coproduct

For the following:

**Question:**  Use the universal property of coproducts to show that, for three sets $A, B$ and $C$, the coproducts $(A\sqcup B)\sqcup C$ and $A\sqcup (B \sqcup C)$ are equipollent.  Therefore we can write $A\sqcup B\sqcup C$.

What I would like to know is what would be a good notation for denoting $(A\sqcup B)\sqcup C=A\sqcup (B \sqcup C),$ in terms of set builder notation, where $A=\{(a ,i )| a\in A ,  i\in I\}$, $B =\{(b ,j )| b\in B,  j\in J\}$ and $C =\{(c ,k )| c\in C,  k\in K \}$. Would it be something like the following cases, where the first is only for the case of three sets, and the second is for index family of sets:

$(A\sqcup B)\sqcup C=(\{(a ,i )\}\cup \{(b ,j )\})\cup \{(c ,k )\}$ and $A\sqcup (B \sqcup C)=\{(a ,i )\}\cup (\{(b ,j )\}\cup \{(c ,k )\})$.  But what happens if we have in the case of index family of sets where $M\sqcup \{N_i\}_{i\in I}=\{N_i\}_{i\in I}\sqcup M$, then $M=\{m|m\in M\}$,  $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}=\{(n,i)|n\in N_i, i\in I\}$ $ M\sqcup \{N_i\}_{i\in I}=\{m\}\cup \{(n,i)\}$ similarly $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}\sqcup M=\{(n,i)\}\cup \{m\}$

Lastly here is a concrete example for three sets:

Let $A=\{a,b\}$ $B=\{b,c,d\}$ $C=\{c\}$

then

$A\sqcup B=\{(a,1),(b,1)\}\cup \{(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\} =\{(a,1),(b,1),(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\} $

and $(A\sqcup B)\sqcup C=\{(a,1),(b,1),(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\}\cup \{{c}\}=\{(a,1),(b,1),(b,2),(c,2), (d,2),c\}$

Similarly $B\sqcup  C=\{(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\}\cup \{{c}\}$

and $A \sqcup (B\sqcup  C)=\{(a,1),(b,1)\}\cup \{(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\}\cup \{{c}\}=\{(a,1),(b,1),(b,2),(c,2), (d,2),c\}$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your notation is still weird. An equation like $A=\{\,(a,i)\mid a\in A,i\in I\,\}$ does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @Blargoner as a concrete example if I have sets 
$A=\{a,b\}$ $B=\{b,c,d\}$ $C=\{c\}$
then 
$A\sqcup B=\{(a,1),(b,1)\}\cup \{(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\} =\{(a,1),(b,1),(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\} $ and 
$(A\sqcup B)\sqcup C=\{(a,1),(b,1),(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\}\cup \{{c}\}=\{(a,1),(b,1),(b,2),(c,2), (d,2),c\}$

Similarly 

$B\sqcup  C=\{(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\}\cup \{{c}\}$
and 
$A \sqcup (B\sqcup  C)=\{(a,1),(b,1)\}\cup \{(b,2),(c,2), (d,2)\}\cup \{{c}\}=\{(a,1),(b,1),(b,2),(c,2), (d,2),c\}$

Comment: @blargoner similar to this post [Appropriate use of notation for showing that prove that every set is isomorphic to a coproduct of  1 -element sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4583889/appropriate-use-of-notation-for-showing-that-prove-that-every-set-is-isomorphic) you commented earlier..  I am really struggling when it comes to the generalize case when it comes to the cases where either having a single set or the case of coproduct of a multiple number of sets or an indexed family of sets with another single set, also I edited my post to append the concrete example to show

Comment: @blargoner my understanding how to uses tagging with ordered pair notations for concrete cases.  Can you give me correction in how to make my notation more clear please.

Comment: A correct way to write this in set-builder notation would be $A' = \{\,(a,1)\mid a\in A\,\}$, $B'=\{\,(b,2)\mid b\in B\,\}$, and then $A\sqcup B=A'\cup B'$, and so on for more sets.

Comment: In that example if you think of $1$ like the color red, and $2$ like the color green, we're painting the elements of $A$ red to form $A'$, and painting the elements of $B$ green to form $B'$, and the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$ is just the regular union of the painted versions $A'$ and $B'$.

Comment: @blargoner what happens if I add another set $C$ then $(A\sqcup B)\sqcup C=(A'\cup B')\cup C'$, where $C'=\{\{c\}|c\in C\}$.  How does that affect the changes for tagging notation with order pairs.

Comment: If you add a third set you need a third paint color! So set $C'=\{\,(c,3)\mid c\in C\,\}$ for example to form $A\sqcup B\sqcup C=A'\cup B'\cup C'$.

Comment: @blargoner in my other post you comment about any set is isomorphic to the coproduct of 1-element sets, why do I not use ordered pair tagging system?